# make css3 divs float to top

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a chat application where each new message creates a new div that is inserted at the bottom of a container, thus bumping the preceding message(s) toward the top of the container. I can get the messages to be added to the container but can't get the positioning to work correctly.

HTML (example):

```
 <div id='chat_container'>
   <div class='message'>Message 1</div>
   <div class='message'>Message 2</div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
 #chat_container{
                    position: relative;
                    height: 240px;
                }


 .message{
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
         }
```

If I use the above styling, every subsequent .message div box will be inserted into the same place as the previous messages, thus hiding them.  I want to bump message 1 toward the top of the page without having to rely on javascript to update style properties.

Comment: All the solutions I have seen on SO related to this design issue use JavaScript/jQuery to set the scroll bar to the bottom.  The alternative is to add new messages to the top of the `chat_container`.

Comment: The fact that you've mentioned the term "IF" in your statement, by principle it means that there is a condition to be applied so that the program/application/site etc.. can make a decision. If you don't want to use javascript that's fine. But remember something or somewhere there will be a condition. And I don't recall HTML having `if{}else{}`

Comment: I just find it amazing that CSS doesn't have a method for what is essentially positioning div elements relative to the parent container from bottom to top, instead of the other way around.  I'm against doing something like this with JS because it should be handled by CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Almighty [FLEX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) coming to the rescue!

```
#chat_container {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column-reverse
}
.message {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    margin:20px auto;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9cuva73L/)

**Some conceptualization**

> The CSS3 Flexible Box, or flexbox, is a layout mode providing for the
>   arrangement of elements on a page such that the elements behave
>   predictably when the page layout must accommodate different screen
>   sizes and different display devices. For many applications, the
>   flexible box model provides an improvement over the block model in
>   that it does not use floats, nor do the flex container's margins
>   collapse with the margins of its contents.
>
> Many designers will find the flexbox model easier to use. Child
>   elements in a flexbox can be laid out in any direction and can have
>   flexible dimensions to adapt to the display space. Positioning child
>   elements is thus much easier, and complex layouts can be achieved more
>   simply and with cleaner code, as the display order of the elements is
>   independent of their order in the source code. This independence
>   intentionally affects only the visual rendering, leaving speech order
>   and navigation based on the source order.

from Mozilla MDN "[Using CSS flexible boxes"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes)

Comment: good solution. i think we should promote features like flexbox and inline-block over using floats and display:table to accomplish things they weren't really designed for.

Comment: flex is relatively new due to browser support issues, but now that all modern browsers supports it, more people is adopting this model every day since it works like magic in many scenarios that previous CSS didn't cover

Comment: it's getting my 80% there but it's putting all new messages above (instead of below) the first message.  I'm looking through the documentation now...

Comment: I used this in combination with Javascript's insertBefore method and that allowed me to redefine the first child element every time a new message (child) is posted. FLEX is awesome and very much appreciate your help with this!!!

Comment: This isn't working as I expected. I found that the chat box is shrinking when it overflows.  I've looked at severe different ways to get prevent this and can't seem to get it.  Your suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand why are you using JS or whatever, the code just as I posted it works out of the box. If you want to reverse the order, simply change `flex-direction:column-reverse` to `flex-direction:column` but I understood you wanted newer first. Anyways, if not, just change the order, but you don't need any JS at all

Answer (score 0):

Have a solution for your question:

```
<div id='chat_container'>
  <div id='wrapper'>
    <div class='message'>Message 1</div>
    <div class='message'>Message 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#chat_container{
    height: 240px;
    display: table;
}
.wrapper{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.message{
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: this kinda worked but I was having trouble getting with the overflow.  Does this display type respect overflow?  It seems like it's adding new divs without respecting overflow and height in my css.